# How to use debounce on `keyup` with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash, underscore.js

I am trying to catch the user started typing, and stopped typing using the `debounce` function. I tried [Lodash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodash) and [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js).

```
On my textArea
                               v-on:keyup="handler($event)"
```

```
handler: function(e) {
             this.e = e
             if(this.canPublish) {
                 this.setCanNotPublish()
                 this.doStuff()
             }

             var debounceFunction = _.debounce(this.doneTyping(), 5000)
             debounceFunction(e)

         },
```

I am getting really frustrated about this. In pure JavaScript I made the test work. But with Vue.js where it uses v-on events, data, methods ...etc., I am not able to make it work.

#### Method *doneTyping*

```
doneTyping: function () {
                console.log('done typing....')
            }

}
```

#### Method *doStuff*

```
doStuff: function () {
             console.log('started typing....')
         }
```

The intended behaviour is: first the user started typing in the textArea, and it starts the doStuff. And if the user keeps typing in a period shorter than 5 seconds, it will not trigger doStuff again because canPublish is a boolean. Next the user stops typing and then the debounce func is done, and doneTyping fires.

Comment: Can you show your `this.doneTyping` code? `this.doneTyping`  should return a function because the first param in  `_.debounce` is the function.

Comment: @TingsenCheng, added doneTyping, its basic console.log .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do with this two debounced functions, one for started typing which triggers on the leading edge, and one for stopped typing which triggers on the trailing edge.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  created() {
    this.startedTyping = _.debounce(this.startedTyping, 5000, {
      leading: true,
      trailing: false,
    })
    this.stoppedTyping = _.debounce(this.stoppedTyping, 5000, {
      leading: false,
      trailing: true,
    })
  },
  
  methods: {
    handleKeydown() {
      // This triggers on the leading edge
      this.startedTyping()

      // This triggers on the trailing edge (after 5s)
      this.stoppedTyping()
    },
    
    startedTyping() {
      console.log('started typing')
    },
    
    stoppedTyping() {
      console.log('stopped typing')
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.19/lodash.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <textarea @keydown="handleKeydown"></textarea>
</div>
```

Your code is wrong because you are creating a new debounced function every time the handler is called. You need to have only one debounced function instance that you call each time. It's best to create the debounced function in the `created` hook.

I often see code like this:

```
methods: {
  myDebouncedFunc: _.debounce(function () {
    // Do stuff
  }, 1000)
}
```

This is technically not wrong, but you may not realize that the debounced function will be shared across all instances of that component, which may not be what you want. It's usually best to create the debounced function in the `created` hook so that each instance of the component gets its own independent debouncing tracking.

Comment: Quick question, why would you use `keydown` instead of `keyup` on your answer?

Comment: No particular reason, I probably should've used `keyup` to be consistent with yours. It could be `input` as well.

Comment: Is this supposed to get buggy if started typing and stopped include visual components?
So, instead of the console i bind it to a model and show it on screen but it never goes away as i clear it on the stopped method. and the model is coming from vuex, if that makes any difference.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem, but it should work. Instead of logging to the console, you should set/clear a boolean flag and bind that to some element in the template. If it isn't working then there is some other issue happening that I can't know about. Perhaps ask another question?

Comment: You, are right, seems to be different issue. posted here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968511/vuejs-infinite-update-loop-in-a-component-render-function

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to debounce your method.

```js
doneTyping: _.debounce(function (e) {
    console.log('done typing....')
}, 5000)
```

Then you use it like

```js
handler: function(e) {
    this.e = e
    if(this.canPublish){
        this.setCanNotPublish()
        this.doStuff()
    }

    this.doneTyping() // function is debounced
},
```

Comment: can not do that because i need to call `this.setCanNotPublish()` , because am trying to detect user started typing and stopped typing.

Comment: Ok, well you probably want `_.debounce(this.doneTyping, 5000)`. `_.debounce` accepts a function reference. `this.doneTyping` is a reference to a function, `this.doneTyping()` isn't, unless it returns a function, which i doubt.

Comment: i modified the question, added an explanation on what am really aiming for.

Comment: Notice that this maintains common debounce delay for all component instances, which is rarely desirable. A preferable way is to do this like the accepted answer shows